# Let's encrypt renew not work

Tags: lets-encrypt

My  Let's encrypt certificate is outdated today.So I try to reinstall the certificate ,and I got:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/awesomes.cn/fullchain.pem. Your cert will
expire on 2016-07-02. To obtain a new version of the certificate in
the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
- If you like Let's Encrypt, please consider supporting our work by:

 Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

But I still can't visit.If some cache exist? the site is https://www.awesomes.cn/

Comment: When I click on your URL, I get a perfect message for a let's encrypt certificate, so maybe it's really your browser cache that fools you.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser might be fooling you, as pointed out by [TAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162496/tam) your URL is working with valid certificate.

Worth to say that you need to restart http server when changing certs, you certainly did this since it is working.